# Polynomial Factors and applications based on those factors

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial
$$g(x) = x^3 - x^2 - (m^2 + m) x + 2m^2 + 4m + 2$$
is divisible by $x-4$ and all of its zeroes are integers. Find all possible values of $m$.

Comment: I tried using various approaches like algebra bashing and applying my knowledge of the Factor Theorem but its leading to nothing.

Comment: Using $g(4)=0$ should tell you a whole lot just by inserting and solving for $m$. Have you tried that?

Comment: Actually I haven't yet, I'll get back to you in a minute

Comment: I'm getting (m^2+m)(x)=2m^2+4m+50. I don't really know what to do with that.

Comment: Any help on simplifying this?

Comment: I tried everything from dividing to plugging in a few numbers but nothing is working

Answer (score 1):

If $g(4)=0$ then we know that $4^3-4^2-4m^2-4m+2m^2+4m+2=0$. Simplifying gives us:

$64-16-2m^2+2=50-2m^2=0$. This implies that $2m^2=50$. You should be able to solve from here.